# Why does 'Hello World' plunker work in Chrome but not Firefox?

Tags: angularjs, plunker

I'm trying to use Plunker with AngularJS and the default Hello World example works in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Here's a [link to an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/WVfgVqTO0wWKvnGVIWxU?p=info).

Steps to reproduce:
1. New Plunker
2. Choose AngluarJS > 1.2.x
3. A simple Hello World example is created
4. Choose Run

Chrome displays `Hello World!`
Firefox displays `Hello {{name}}!`

Is there something wrong with the AngularJS example that Plunker creates?  Am i doing something wrong here?

I've reproduced this behavior in Windows XP and OSX
Firefox v27.0.1
Chrome v33.0.1750.146m

Comment: Works fine for me in FF 27.0.1, using Windows 7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example dint work for me in Chrome either. I added the ng-app to the html tag so that Angular knows to load the module. So, instead of

```
<html>
```

it should be

```
<html ng-app="plunker">
```

Updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/d8Fb7o8OjUFdXOLKAaS7

Comment: its strange, the default Hello World initially works when i create it in Chrome but when i return using my link it doesn't work there either.  your version works though.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to tell browser what you are using if you are using angularjs then you have to add

if you add this on then scope of this for whole html'

```
    <html ng-app="plunker">
```

and if you add this then scope for angularjs is available for body

```
   <body ng-app="plunker">
```

it is fast comparison to including in html but main point  is that you have to add `ng-app`